# Deploy a list definition (.stp) in app catalog in Sharepoint 2013 Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013

I wonder if there is a way to add a list definition in a SharePoint app catalog site. The list definition is generated from a custom list I can't use Visual Studio to package a wsp.

Comment: Everything that goes in App Catalog is published as an app. You haven't specified enough details to suggest but you may want to look at - SharePoint Hosted Model.